# Spring 2 + JUnit 5, share @MockBean for entire test suite

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit5, spring-test

I create a Spring 2.3 application using Spring Data REST, Hibernate, Mysql.
I created my tests, I've around 450 tests splitted in about 70 files. Because the persistence layer leans on a multi tenant approach (single db per tenant) using a Hikari connection pool, I've the need to avoid the pool is initializated for each test file but at the same time I need to use `@MockBean` because I need to mock up some repositories in the entire Spring test contest.

I create a custom annotation for all test in my suite:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@SpringBootTest
@TestExecutionListeners(value = TestExecutionListener.class, mergeMode = TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
@Transactional
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public @interface TestConfig {
}
```

Reading many posts and the doc, I know if I use @MockBean inside a test, the Spring context is reloaded and therefore a new pool connection is created in my case.
My idea is to create a @MockBean and share it with all tests in my suite so the context is not reloaded every time.

I tried several approaches:

```
@Log4j2
public class TestExecutionListener extends AbstractTestExecutionListener implements Ordered {
@Override
public void beforeTestMethod(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
    try {
        TestDbUtils testDbUtils = (TestDbUtils) testContext.getApplicationContext().getBean(TestDbUtils.class);
        testDbUtils.truncateDB();
        TenantRepository tenantRepository = mock(TenantRepository.class);
        testContext.setAttribute("tenantRepository", tenantRepository);
        TenantContext.setCurrentTenantId("test");
        when(tenantRepository.findByTenantId("test")).thenReturn(testDbUtils.fakeTenant());

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
}
```

All my tests are annotated like this:

```
@TestConfig
@Log4j2
public class InvoiceTests {

@Test
public void test1(){
}
}
```

Unfortunately my `tenantRepository.findByTenantId()` is not mocked up. I also tried to create an abstract superclass:

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
@TestExecutionListeners(value = TestExecutionListener.class, mergeMode = TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
@Transactional
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest {
    @MockBean
    protected TenantRepository tenantRepository;

    @MockBean
    protected SubscriptionRepository subscriptionRepository;

    @Autowired
    protected TestDbUtils testDbUtils;

    @BeforeAll
    public void beforeAll() {
        when(tenantRepository.findByTenantId("test")).thenReturn(testDbUtils.fakeTenant());
    }

    @BeforeEach       
    public void setup() {
        testDbUtils.truncateDB();
        TenantContext.setCurrentTenantId("test");

    }
}
```

Even if my tests extended this superclass, during the run all of them were skipped (not sure why).

Is there any way to accomplish what I described?

Comment: The context is only reloaded IF the config is different, so if you use exact the same config with the same MockBeans the config isn't reloaded. At least it shouldn't. I also don't really get parts of your custom annotation. You don't need the `TestPropertySource` as that one is already loaded by Spring Boot itself. The `@WithMockAdminuser` should be on the class not on the `setup` method. Instead of the `@MockBean` you cn also add a config that uses `Mockito.mock` to create the mock for your repo and load that as well.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for your hints. THe WithMockAdminuser was a wrong copy and paste ;-) About the TestPropertySource, thanks for the suggestion. About your sentence, you are saying that if I do use the same MockBean in each test, the context should be the same and therefore should not be reloaded? I tried to use Mockito.mock but the point is the mocked repository is used in many inner services of my application, so when I run the test I want the mocked up service is used everywhere in the execution of the test. With Mockito.mock I can't do that, am I right?

Comment: Why not, place it in an `@Bean` method in a config class. That makes it a bean for injection but still a mock. The context is only reloaded if one of the testexecutionlistner, properties, mockbeans, config classes/files are different. All of those are part of the cache key for the context (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching)

Comment: @M.Deinum maybe I was not clear. When I mean the mock bean should be available everywhere, I mean if I've a ContactRepository in my application and I mock it in my tests, in every point of my application where I use that repository, it should be *replaced* by the mock. Maybe I'm wrong but it doesn't seem with mock(ContactRepository.class) I can do it. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it can IF it is defined as a bean and as mentioned `@MockBean` in your test does the same.